# Access data from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass data from child component to parent component and then trigger `setState`.

### Parent.jsx

```
onChildChange(cv) {
  // do something . NEED TO ACCESS cv here!!!!
}
render() {
  return <MyClild childValue={switchVal} onChildChange={ this.onChildChange(cv) }/>;
}
```

### Child.jsx

```
render(){
  let valuefromchild='blah blah';
  return(
    <div onClick={ this.props.onChildChange(valuefromchild) } >
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: This works well when I don't pass any values. But when I pass values from child to parent some how does not work

Answer (score 3):

You are executing function rather than passing as a parameter. Change your code accordingly to the below.

```
onChildChange(cv) {
  console.log(cv);
}
render() {
  return <MyClild childValue={switchVal} onChildChange={ this.onChildChange }/>;
}
```

---

```
render() {
  let valuefromchild = 'blah blah';
  return (
    <div onClick={ (event) => this.props.onChildChange(valuefromchild) } >
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @alowsarwar updated `onClick` prop. Please try again with the updated code.